# mongodb - authentication failure on phpmongodb with username

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, database, mongodb

I have a problem to authenticating to mongodb. The system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I can connect locally:

```
$ mongo mytestdb -u mongotest -p MYPASSWORD
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: mytestdb
Server has startup warnings:
2016-02-22T10:53:07.557+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-02-22T10:53:07.557+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
2016-02-22T10:53:07.557+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
```

But when I try to connect from outside (using `phpmongodb`), I am getting the following message on browser login:

```
Note: Failed to connect to: 12.345.67.890:27017: Authentication failed on database 'mongotest' with username 'mongotest': auth failed
```

The port is listening:

```
$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 27017
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7570/mongod
```

The firewall is open:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8880
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:poppassd
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9008
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmptype 8 code 0
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27017

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:27017
```

My mongodb config file:

```
$ cat /etc/mongod.conf
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#   bindIp: 12.345.67.890
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

#processManagement:

#security:
#  auth=true

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Nothing works - I cannot connect to db.

Comment: You can connect to the database, this is proven by the fact that you are getting an authentication failure.  You cannot fail authentication without connecting successfully first, so your issue is not system or network/firewall related. You either have the wrong password, or possibly based on your config file, you do not have authentication enabled (can't auth if it is not enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are trying to auth in front of the correct database, (if you created the user in the admin db or other db), you have you auth in the server that the user was created or else it will show you the error you see